# ADB Shell giving bad mode when executing chmod (under su)

Tags: android, shell, adb, chmod, android-2.2-froyo

I'm having an issue related to the Android ADB Shell. When I try to execute the command chmod he gives me a "Bad Mode". I don't get it why. I'm sure I'm executing under "su", as represented by the '#'. Anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how to make it work? Thanks in advance.

`chmod o+rw /dev/ttyS1`

Comment: did you try `chmod 600 /dev/ttyS1` or other octal values appropriate for the permissions you want to use? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to open with 666. Post it as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Bad mode means the permissions on the file are not set correctly, and some versions of `chmod` don't understand the `o+rw` notation. All `chmod`s understand octal notation, where 6=read/write, so try

```
 chmod 666 /dev/ttyS1
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use /system/xbin/busybox chmod

example:

busybox chmod u+s /system/xbin/busybox

Comment: Bravo. This is the only solution for me. Thank you.